# Unable to call a controller action method using Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, action

I am working in MVC4.
    I have a controller named "Beauty". It has two action methods namely, "Actio1" and "Action2".
    My view name is Action1.
    Now in my view i have two divs. On click of the first div, through AJAX i am calling "Action1" method in my controller. This is working fine i.e., i am able to hit the action method "Action1".
    When I click the second div and try to call the second action method "Action2" through AJAX, I am unable to hit the Action2 method at all.

**Controller**

```
public class BeautyController : Controller 
{ 
   [HttpPost] public JsonResult Action1(string option1) 
   { 
      return Json("true"); 
   }     

   [HttpPost] public JsonResult Action2(string option2)
   {
      return Json("true"); 
   }
}
```

**Ajax**

```
function Question1(Answers) {
   var url = '@Url.Action("Action1", "Beauty")'; 
   var Data = Answers;

   if (url != null && url != undefined && Data != null && Data != undefined) {
      $.ajax({ url: url,
               dataType: "json",
               type: "POST", 
               data: { 'option': Answers },
               contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
               success: function (result) {
                  if (result != null && result != undefined && result == "true")
                  { 
                     alert("Successfully Inserted!"); 
                  }
               },
               error: function (result) {
                  alert("error"); 
               } 
       });
   }
}
```

Can you please help me identify the issue and resolve it.

Thanks,
Priya.

Comment: Please show some code, Priya

Comment: Hi Dumisani,my controller is public class BeautyController : Controller {
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Action1(string option1)
        {
            return Json("true");
        }  
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Action2(string option2)
        {
            return Json("true");
        }
 } and my AjAX call in the following comment

Comment: function Question1(Answers) {var url = '@Url.Action("Action1", "Beauty")'; var Data = Answers;if (url != null && url != undefined && Data != null && Data != undefined) {$.ajax({ url: url, dataType: "json",type: "POST", data: { 'option': Answers }, contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', success: function (result) {if (result != null && result != undefined && result == "true") { alert("Successfully Inserted!");  } },error: function (result) { alert("error");  } });}}

Comment: Are you saying when you change `@Url.Action("Action1", "Beauty")` to `@Url.Action("Action2", "Beauty")` nothing happens?

Comment: Yes Dumisani. I tried debugging, the control does not go to Action2 at all.

Comment: Try also changing `data: { 'option': Answers },` to `data: { 'option2': Answers },`. Also please show the part where you call the `Question1` function if that doesn't work

Comment: Yea what Dumisani said, I'm confused as to why Action1 whould be called since that parameter is called `option1` not `option` The parameter name must match the JSON property. So it must be either `data: { option1: Answers }` or `data: { option2: Answers }`. I would also try removing the quotes off of `'option1/2'`

Answer (score 0):

You have hardcoded the url to action1

```
 var url = '@Url.Action("Action1", "Beauty")';
```

If you want that to call Action2 you would need to change it to:

```
 var url = '@Url.Action("Action2", "Beauty")';
```

However that would then only call Action 2.

I would suggest that you consider using a data attribute on the divs in question.

So something like this:

```
 <div id="div1" data-url="@Url.Action("Action1", "Beauty")">
     //Div content here
 </div>

 <div id="div2" data-url="@Url.Action("Action2", "Beauty")">
     //Div content here
 </div>
```

Then wherever you are calling the function from I am guessing a click event. You would have some jQuery like this:

```
 var url = $(this).data("url");
```

Which you would then pass through to your question function so it would become something along the lines of this:

```
 function Question1(Answers, url) {
   var Data = Answers;
   if (url != null && url != undefined && Data != null && Data != undefined) {
   $.ajax({ url: url,
           dataType: "json",
           type: "POST", 
           data: { 'option': Answers },
           contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
           success: function (result) {
              if (result != null && result != undefined && result == "true")
              { 
                 alert("Successfully Inserted!"); 
              }
           },
           error: function (result) {
              alert("error"); 
           } 
       });
       }
     }
```

Obiously this answer is based on the pieces of information you have provided above and some assumptions.